# Assets 2 "add image button"

Tags: control-panel, assets

In Assets 1 you could select several images and then click add to add them all at once. This is still possible in Assets 2, but the button has been removed from the interface. When you select several images and double-click the selection the images will be added. But this requires precise timing. 
Please consider bringing back the add button.

Before:
[image: Assets 1, Add button marked]

After:

[image: Assets 2, no Add button]

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Florian.  I'll follow this up with our team.

Comment: This is a feature request, not a question. Please do not post feature requests here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot.